# Add samba folder to favorite into finder sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, active-directory, smb

I have client stations (OS X Yosemite) bound into Active Directory services. When the user was authorized I prepared his profile from /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj/* and settings for machine is synced from Open Directory (practices named magic triangle.)

The record in AD contains samba shared folder for every user. When I enable Show Connected Server in Finder preferences on Desktop, they have icons for this disk on desktop.

How do I add this link into favorites in Finder sidebar?

In section Servers there is a general link to Share Disk and I need link to a specific folder for every logged-in user as a link on their Desktops.

Are there best practices I should be following?

Without practise when every user drag and drop the link from desktop to favorite? My users every day change the working place and this practise is wrong.

thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 10):

I found out, that the following process adds a folder mounted on a samba share to the sidebar/favorites in my finder. They 'survive' a restart of my mac. I guess they also work as intended if you reboot the NAS/server/whatever. To achieve that, do execute the following steps:

- Mount the shared folder (it should be listed in the sidebar under 'Shared' within the finder).
- Within the finder, go to View -> Show Path Bar
- Navigate to the folder within your SMB share so that you are in the folder that you wish to add to the sidebar.
- Grab the icon at the bottom above your status bar left of the name of the folder you are in and drag it to your sidebar.
- With a click on this sidebar folder you should land/stay in your desired folder on your samba share.
- (optional step) Go to View -> 'Hide Path Bar' if you don't like this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow but if I understand it, you are mounting a deep path from the SMB share, but the root of that share is listed under 'Shared' in the sidebar. This is expected behavior and I don't believe you can change it.

It's also in theory possible to add items to the sidebar by modifying ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SideBarLists.plist , but this is a non-trivial task because the entries include several items encoded in an undocumented format. A good overview of this is linked in [this comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139305/how-can-i-add-new-folders-to-the-favorites-in-the-finder-sidebar?rq=1#comment208735_139306) on a similar question.

I would suggest trying to copy some known-good entries from this plist and seeing if they are portable, but if every user is going to be adding different locations that's probably not viable. There also doesn't seem to be any Applescript facility for this, either.

I would suggest looking in to creating these shortcuts as dock items or simple aliases in a folder, instead of trying to crack the sidebar enigma.