# Cannot add applications to favorites bar in Finder

Tags: finder, sidebar

I am a new Macbook user, which is exciting but alas confusing as well. I am trying to add favorites in the side bar under Finder. I read that one can just drag and drop from Applications as in this thread - [How can I add new folders to the Favorites in the Finder sidebar?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139305/how-can-i-add-new-folders-to-the-favorites-in-the-finder-sidebar).

However, when I have done it, it does not stick and the icon just goes back into the Applications list as if I have not done anything.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong or why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although this tip does not add Application Alias' to the Sidebar, they can be added to the toolbar.

#### Add Application Shortcuts (Alias') to the Finder Toolbar

- Open 2 Finder Windows (From Finder use <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
- Be sure one of them is showing your Applications Folder and both can be seen on screen together
- Using the other Finder Window, right click or <kbd>option</kbd>+click in the toolbar area and select **Customize Toolbar...** from the dropdown.  (This can also be accessed from the Menu - View > Customize Toolbar...)
- Drag your desired application from the **first window (your Applications Folder)** to the **Toolbar on the Finder Window being edited**.  Select *Done* button and all Finder Windows will now display your favorite Apps for quick access.  See the screenshots below.

[image: Toolbar options]

[image: Toolbar with Apps]

Answer (score 0):

You can only add favorites **Directories** to the finder sidebar.

But you can add some favorites applications on the **Dock** :
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201730

Answer (score 0):

command-drag the application to the Favorite Sidebar.
Although, since Ventura, dragging stuff onto these apps does not work anymore.