# Open file/folder in Wine explorer in Finder

Tags: macos, mac, finder, wine

I am using `wine explorer` via macOS terminal.

Once the Wine Explorer is open, can I select a file or folder and "open" it in Finder?

[image: folder]

Answer (score 5):

From [the Mac Forums](https://www.mac-forums.com/switcher-hangout/291764-path-wine-program-files.html)

> In Finder, push Shift-Command-G and enter the following:
>
> ```
> ~/.wine/drive_c/
> ```
>
> Navigate from there to find the name of the relevant folder.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to "click" on a folder in Wine and have it open in Finder because, technically, you're in a Windows environment.

However, with a little info from the [official Wine documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Drive_Settings) we can make some tweaks to Finder to easily get access to the drive.

All of Wine's user configuration files are in a hidden directory in the user's home: `~/.wine`.  The `C:` ("C" drive) can be found  in `~/.wine/drive_c`.

Using a simple Terminal command, we can [create a symbolic link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/240552/119271) to `C:` on the Desktop:

```
$ ln -s ~/.wine/drive_c ~/Desktop/C_Drive
```

Or... the home folder (it won't clutter your Desktop this way)

```
$ ln -s ~/.wine/drive_c ~/C_Drive
```

Once you have that (symlinked) folder created, you can [add it to your favorites](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139306/119271) on the Finder sidebar.

Keep in mind, you're not limited to just the root of the `C:` or just a directory:

```
$ ln -s ~/.wine/drive_c/foo/bar/folder ~/Desktop/Foo_Bar_Folder

$ ln -s ~/.wine/drive_c/foo/bar/file.txt ~/Desktop/Foo_Bar_Notepad_Document.txt
```

The advantage of using this method is that you can get "easy" access from both the Finder GUI and from Terminal. For instance (assuming the symlink is in the home directory)

```
$ cd ~/C_Drive
```

Will take you to `C:` without having to remember to traverse the whole hidden directory `~/.wine/drive_c`.