# Where are Wineskin application files stored?

Tags: finder, wine

In 2020 or 2021 I installed a Wineskin wrapper for Heroes of Might and Magic 3 (HOMM3) on my Mac. I now need to back all those files up, but I have issues trying to locate where the save games are actually stored, meaning the folder typically stored in `~/.wine/drive_c/` in standard Wine install. There is no `.wine` folder, of course.

I have searched all of my `$HOME` drive for 'AUTOSAVE.CGM' and other save game files, but no go. I have also searched for `drive_c` and other variations, still no go.

I found the launchers/wrappers in the `$HOME/Applications/Wineskin` folders, so also tried searching them:

```
find  ~/Applications/Wineskin/Heroes\ of\ Might\ and\ Magic\ 3\ HD.app/drive_c/ -iname '*cgm'
```

No go. It is like it is on some shadow drive?

```
$ find . -iname '*cgm'
$ find . -iname '*h3m' | wc -l
     159
$ pwd
/Users/myuser/Applications/Wineskin/Heroes of Might and Magic 3 HD.app/drive_c
$ du -chs .
1.2G    .
1.2G    total
```

To be honest, I don't really remember installing Wineskin myself, and the [recommended installation of using Homebrew](https://brew%20install%20--no-quarantine%20gcenx/wine/unofficial-wineskin) should list something when doing `brew list` right? But it does not. So either it is Crossover (doubt it) or Wineskin. From folder names, definitely looks like the latter, but I could also just have gotten a finished wrapper. The problem of locating the drive remains, either way :)

[Related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345487/open-file-folder-in-wine-explorer-in-finder).

Comment: Did you (with Finder or Terminal/ls) look into `Applications/Wineskin/Heroes*HD.app/drive_c/`? Is there anything stored there at all?

Comment: @nohillside As I wrote above, I used the `find` command to try and locate any save game files there. None were found. There are lots of other files, though, including the install files (1.2GB according to `du`). Like `drive_c/GOG Games/HoMM 3 Complete/`

Comment: Can you run the game and does it find the saved files?

Comment: I got it. I have out-tricked myself using symlinks. I will update the question and add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say this was years ago, I expect you installed [Wineskin](https://web.archive.org/web/20130906024045/http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/), not [WineskinServer](https://github.com/Gcenx/WineskinServer). For the former:

> Wrappers made here are placed by default in...
>
> ~/Applications/Wineskin  (where ~ means your home folder)

https://web.archive.org/web/20130906024045/http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php?page=Manual+2.3+Wrappers

You could have placed it anywhere though.

The `drive_c` folder inside the wrapper should contain your files.

> drive_c is a folder that all Windows apps run from this wrapper will see as the computers C: drive.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140825110833/http://wineskin.urgesoftware.com/tiki-index.php?page=Manual+3.1+A+look+Inside+a+Wrapper

Comment: Sorry, I was exaggerating ... This was 2020 or 2021. But the location is right, as you can see from my post which lists `$HOME/Applications/Wineskin`. Unfortunately, only the install files (Windows + game files) are there, 1.2GB in total, but the save games seems to be stored elsewhere? Is it possible that there is some kind overlay filesystem for user files that stores user generated files somewhere else? The save games would normally have been stored in `%AppData%/Local/...` in the user's home directory.

Comment: I found the answer. Updating.

Answer (score 2):

My question had a big issue: the title was not reflecting what I was looking for ... I was wondering why the save games for HOMM3 was not anywhere to be found in the `~/Applications/$MyApp.app/drive_c` location, but it turns out they kind of were and kind of were not.

> It is like it is on some shadow drive?

My comment was spot on. They were not physically there, only logically:

```
idas-imac:drive_c $ find . -type l -print0 | xargs -0  ls -lh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 idaangelweum  staff    44B Feb 17  2021 ./GOG Games/HoMM 3 Complete/Games -> /Users/ida/Dropbox/Savegames/HOMM3/
```

Turns out that I had forgotten that I had replaced the `Games` folder with a symbolic link to a folder for save games in Dropbox and forgotten about it  This explains why the `find` command could not find it, since it does not follow symbolic links into other directories.

So awarding the answer to @grg, as he did in fact answer the question to where the files were.